# Is it possible to easily count all the possible distinct sums from distinct numbers?

Tags: combinatorics

For example, given four distinct numbers $5, 6, 7, 9$
We have $2^4-1$ sums, $5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12, 14, 13, 15, 16, 18, 22, 20, 21, 27$ which are the sums from the numbers.

But if given five distinct numbers $5, 6, 7, 8, 9$,
then we see $5 + 9 = 6 + 8$, hence the possible distinct sums of them cannot be easily counted by $2^5-1$.

Is it possible to easily count all the possible distinct sums from distinct numbers? Thanks!

Comment: $2^4$ and $2^5$ if you count $0$ as a sum too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's rather easy to count the total number of possible sums this way. But the actually different sums is a different matter: the knapsack problem says it's NP hard to determine whether some number $n$ is among those sums for a concrete set of numbers.

For [superincreasing sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superincreasing_sequence) all sums will be different. This has been the idea of building a public key encryption system, in fact: to modify a superincreasing sequence so that we still keep the unique sums property (so we have the maximal number of sums). $1,2,4,8, \ldots$ is superincreasing.

Counting the number of different sums in other cases could turn out to be pretty hard, I don't expect a closed formula for this to exist. But an algorithm does exist, see [here](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/20713?) e.g.

Also see [this question and its answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1915792/4280)